# Macro to hide line from excel chart and line in legend

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that hides the line in my excel chart. The problem however is even though the macro removes the line from the chart, it still appears in the legend as blank.

How can I modify my code so to address this?

Code:

```
Sub Macro1()    
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Visible = _
        Not ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Visible
End Sub
```

Problem with legend:
[image: excel chart]

Edit: 
Buttons
[image: buttons]

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to remove the 2ns series from the Legend:

```
ActiveChart.Legend.LegendEntries(2).Delete
```

---

A cleaner approach, using fully defined Objects without using `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveChart` will be:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim MyCht As ChartObject

' set the chart object
Set MyCht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects(1) ' "Chart 1") ' modify the "Sheet1" and "Chart 1" according to your needs

With MyCht
    .Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Visible = Not .Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.Visible

    .Chart.Legend.LegendEntries(2).Delete

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem with this is when I click the button back on, I don't have my legend anymore?

Comment: What button ? where is that in your code ? you didn't mention that in your post

Comment: Ideally I will have it so if the button is checked, the line is showed in the graph, and if it is unchecked the line is not showed in the graph. The problem I was running into before was even though my code removed the line, it would not remove the legend entry for that line

Comment: Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @newtoR yes, that's a whole other story

Comment: Oh, can you still help me though?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IsFiltered` for this:

```
Sub tester()

    Dim cht As Chart

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart

    HideShowSeries cht, "Series1", False 'hide series1
    HideShowSeries cht, "Series1", True  'show series1

    HideShowSeries cht, "", False 'hide all series
    HideShowSeries cht, "", True  'show all series

End Sub

Sub HideShowSeries(cht As Chart, seriesname As String, show As Boolean)
    Dim s As Series
    For Each s In cht.FullSeriesCollection
        If s.Name = seriesname Or seriesname = "" Then
            s.IsFiltered = Not show
        End If
    Next s
End Sub
```